# Не воспринимается id при передаче его как параметр

Tags: c#

При вызове метода по ссылке `localhost:63844/Vehicle?shipperId=@id` id воспринимается как строка и не преобразуется в id перевозчика

а должно быть вроде этого: `localhost:63844/Vehicle?shipperId=1`

```
 HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["authCookie"];
     string id = cookie.Values["id"];`

 string menuItemsPath = "~/Views/MenuItems/";
    string ext = ".cshtml";
 IHtmlString vehicles = 
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(menuItemsPath + "Vehicles" + ext)));

<ul class="logistian-menu nav navbar-nav">
    @shipperClaims @auction @tender @rating @free @createDriver @createVehicle @drivers @vehicles
</ul>

//Вызов в Vehicle.cshtml
<li><a href="../Vehicle?shipperId=@id">ТС</a></li>
```

Comment: Ну что открываешь, то и получается.

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: На какой адрес посылается запрос и откуда по-твоему сервер должен угадать, какой id в нём хотел видеть пользователь?

Comment: такой же случай с logistianId и там все в точности также,только вызов метода другой и там id считывается корректно и показывается число вместо @id

Comment: "../Settings/Logistian?logistianId=@id"

Comment: Покажите весь код - из вашего вопроса непонятен контекст, и непонятно, почему вы ожидаете какой-то замены ID И что такое logistianId. Сам по себе C# никаких @id ни на что не заменяет :)

Comment: `IHtmlString vehicles = @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(menuItemsPath + "Vehicles" + ext)));
`

Comment: `HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["authCookie"];
    string id = cookie.Values["id"];`

Comment: `string menuItemsPath = "~/Views/MenuItems/";
    string ext = ".cshtml";`

Comment: Пишите ваш код в текст вопроса, используйте кнопку **[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1002019/edit)**

Comment: <li><a href="../Vehicle?shipperId=@id">ТС</a></li>  эта строка в какой функции создаётся у вас?

Answer (score 0):

Вы выводите содержимое Vehicles.cshtml как строку, при этом код в нем не выполняется, а выводится как есть. Чтобы код выполнялся - надо рендерить этот файл через Razor:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Vehicles", new { id = id });}
```

примерно так

```
<ul class="logistian-menu nav navbar-nav">
    @shipperClaims @auction @tender @rating @free @createDriver @createVehicle @drivers 

    @{Html.RenderPartial("Vehicles", new { id = id });}
</ul>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь